# issues with === in typescript

Tags: if-statement, angular6, typescript3.0

**I have an if block as given below:**

`if (this.totalTenants === 1) {
      this.newTenants.tenant2 = Object.assign({ name: null, number: null }, this.emptyTenant);
      this.newTenants.tenant3 = Object.assign({ name: null, number: null }, this.emptyTenant);
      this.newTenants.tenant4 = Object.assign({ name: null, number: null }, this.emptyTenant);
      this.newTenants.tenant2 = this.emptyTenant;
      this.newTenants.tenant3 = this.emptyTenant;
      this.newTenants.tenant4 = this.emptyTenant;
      this.newTenants.rentAmount = 3200;
}`

But when the value of **this.totalTenants** is 1 it doesn't go into the if block.

I'm working on Angular 6 with typescript.

If I if (this.totalTenants == 1) *double equals sign ==*

then the if block is executed but I get the error as displayed below:
[tslint] == should be === (triple-equals)

Comment: add a plus (+) before this.totalTenants like 
 if (+this.totalTenants === 1){....}

Comment: Add a `console.log(this.totalTenants)` to assure yourself that `totalTenants` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `==` and `===` operators is that the first make an automatic cast to facilitate comparison, the second one does not cast anything.

So if you try to compare two number values, but one of them is a string representation of the number, comparison fails with `===` operator.

Probably you are using a string value like '1', to check this you can execute something like this:

```
console.log(typeof this.totalTenants)
```

If it resulsts in a string you should change your operator to `==` or cast that value to a number prepending the variable with `+` like this:

```
if (+this.totalTenants === 1) {
```